# Why is ONLY the first cell data wrong or blank when inserting data from txt file into Access using VB?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, text-files

I am trying to insert some data from a txt file into an temporary table in Access using VB.

All the data imports correctly except for the first cell, which either seems to be corrupted or blank.

The text file is created in notepad and is as follows

```
22/07/20,45301,N
22/07/20,44810,N
22/07/20,51681,N
22/07/20,46570,N
```

The vb code inserting the data is as follows

```
'create new table called tempret
 cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [tempret] ([DATE] DATE, [UNIQUE NUMBER] INTEGER, [INSTORE] CHAR);"
 Try
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     Console.WriteLine("table created.")
 Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Creating TempRet Table")
 End Try
' MsgBox("Check tempret exists")
'insert data from txt file into tempret
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tempret] " &
     "([Date], [UNIQUE NUMBER], [INSTORE]) " &
     "SELECT F1, F2, F3 FROM " &
     "[Text;DATABASE=" & DatabasePath & ";HDR=No].[RETURNS.txt]"
 Try
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     Console.WriteLine("Data Inserted into Temp Table.")
 Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Inserting Data into TempRet Table")
 End Try
```

Then the table in Access look like this

[image: Access temp table with missing data in first cell]

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the file the data is being taken from happen to have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which could be confusing things?

Comment: Thank you! That may be it!  I will try and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

The Text file was saved as "UTF-8 with BOM". Changing it to "UTF-8" fixed all the problems!

Credit to Andrew Morton, spot on!